# AWS - Installing Tomcat 8 on EC2

Tags: tomcat, amazon-ec2, tomcat8, yum

I’m trying to install Tomcat8 on EC2 (I installed Java8 first). However, when I try to list all available tomcats using:

```
yum list available | grep tomcat
```

tomcat versions do not show up and this is what I get:

[image]

Moreover, when I installed the tomcat in the snapshot above using this command:

```
yum install tomcat tomcat-webapps tomcat-admin-webapps tomcat-docs-webapp
```

then I tried to start the server using:

```
service tomcat start
```

I ended up with:

```
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl start tomcat.service
```

and the server  doesn't work.

Can you help please?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As a workaround, I downloaded Tomcat9 on my laptop, copied it to the EC2 instance using  linux "scp" command, then installed it there.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
amazon-linux-extras list
```

and you'll see tomcat8.5 in the list.

Now following to install :

```
sudo amazon-linux-extras install tomcat8.5
```